# How to Ignore a Synthesis constraint if signal is not in design?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have a clock in my design that drives some logic in normal operation.  However occasionally I want to disable this block of logic by setting a VHDL generic to disable it.  But I still have a clock constraint in my .xcf file e.g:

```
NET "TEST_CLK" TNM_NET = "TEST_CLK";
TIMESPEC TS_TEST_CLK = PERIOD "TEST_CLK" 20.000 ns HIGH 50 %;
```

If I try to run synthesis I get the following error:

```
Processing TIMESPEC TS_TEST_CLK: No TNM or User group name TEST_CLK is defined.
```

How can I tell the tools to effectively ignore this constraint when the clock has been (correctly) optimized out of the design?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Two ideas; Vivado uses TCL in XDC file so if you can use Vivado it should be possible to do conditional constrains through TCL; alternative is to keep a `TEST_CLK` signal with a single dummy flip-flop to avoid breaking the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Vivado issues a Critical Warning for constraints that do not match the design, however it continues to build and will generate a .bit file anyway. I think this is a nice tradeoff, but you have to remember to look at the critical warnings.

Also, as Morten Zilmer commented, Vivado uses a TCL file for the constraints, so you can conditionalize the constraints or generate them based on the actual design.

Answer (score 0):

When using the ISE tools, ngdbuild (Translate) has the "allow unmatched timing group" option (-aut on the command line). This is supposed to be used when you have an incomplete design. There ought to be an option under translate properties in the gui also. If you are adding the constraint at synthesis I'm not sure there is an option to specifically do this.